# Inserting unicode into NVARCHAR with SQL Server placeholders

Tags: sql-server, unicode

Using SQL Server the way to insert unicode data into an `NVARCHAR` field is like

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (name, address) 
VALUES (N'Test data', N'More test data');
```

i.e. using `N` before the string literal. But what if we are using the placeholder way of inserting data like

```
# generated data elsewhere in code, stored in variables
x = 'Test data'
y = 'More test data'

insert_cmd = "INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (name, address) VALUES (?, ?);"
curs.execute(insert_cmd, (x,y))
```

How do I apply the `N` casting with this way of doing the insert?

Comment: what language do you use?

Comment: When inserting from a "client" language, you must ensure that your language / programming system uses and supports Unicode. The `N` prefix can only be applied to **string literals** in SQL scripts that you run (in SSMS or programmatically)